# Calling an anonymous function within function declaration

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, invoke

Trying to access an anonymous function 'raining' by passing an argument

```
function weather(){
    function sunny(){
        return "Sun is shining!";
    }
    console.log(sunny());

    var raining = function(num){
        var rainThisWeek = " ";
        for (var d = 0; d < num; d++){
            rainThisWeek += "pelting ";
        }
        return rainThisWeek;
    }
}
weather();
```

Comment: Same way you would call any function, `raining(3)` or something similar?

Comment: The function `raining` is not returned by the function nor is it assigned to any global or enclosed variable therefore it gets garbage collected (deleted) immediately after `weather()` returns

Answer (score 1):

You can use function currying to access the anonymous function inside `weather()`. Basically it means returning the anonymous function reference from the outer function and executing it with the expected parameter.

```js
function weather(){
    function sunny(){
        return "Sun is shining!";
    }
    console.log(sunny());

    var raining = function(num){
        var rainThisWeek = " ";
        for (var d = 0; d < num; d++){
            rainThisWeek += "pelting";
        }
        return rainThisWeek;
    }
    return raining; //you can curry the anonymous function
}
//-----------------v This will return the anonymous function reference
console.log(weather()(4)); 
//--------------------^ This will execute the returned anonymous function with the parameter 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks for this type of requirement.

```
function weather(cb){
 cb();
}

var raining = function(num){
 var rainThisWeek = " ";
 for (var d = 0; d < num; d++){
  rainThisWeek += "pelting";
 }
 return rainThisWeek;
}

function sunny(){
 return "Sun is shining!";
}

// for sunny pass sunny as callback to weather function

weather(sunny)

// for raining pass raining as callback to weather function

weather(raining.bind(null, 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined the raining method, you can't access it outside the function. You either need to return the method

```js
  function weather(){
        function sunny(){
            return "Sun is shining!";
        }
        console.log(sunny());
    
        var raining = function(num){
            var rainThisWeek = " ";
            for (var d = 0; d < num; d++){
                rainThisWeek += "pelting";
            }
            return rainThisWeek;
        }
        return raining
    }
    weather()(4);
```

or define it on instance or prototype

```js
function weather(){
        function sunny(){
            return "Sun is shining!";
        }
        console.log(sunny());
    
        this.raining = function(num){
            var rainThisWeek = " ";
            for (var d = 0; d < num; d++){
                rainThisWeek += "pelting";
            }
            return rainThisWeek;
        }
    }
    const weather1 = new weather();
    console.log(weather1.raining(3));
```